# How to get UPN from X509Certificate in java

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, client-certificates, subject-alternative-name

In our web-application we are about to refine certificate authentication mechanism.

We used to use `CN` from the certificate to get login and authenticate the user.

However, requirements have changed and now we are advised to use `SAN` (Subject Alternative Name) both `UPN`  or `RFC822 Name`

In our certificate `SAN` field I see the following:

```
Other Name:
   Principal Name=EXAMPLE@vw.vwg
RFC822 Name=Extern.Example.Example@volkswagen.de
```

I've tried to get RFC822 Name with the following snippet:

```
public static String getSANOtherNameRFC822(X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateParsingException
{
     Collection<List<?>> subjectAlternativeNames = cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames();

     for (List<?> subjectAlternativeName : subjectAlternativeNames)
     {
        if ((Integer) subjectAlternativeName.get(0) == 1) // rfc822name
        {
            System.out.println((String) subjectAlternativeName.get(1));
            return (String) subjectAlternativeName.get(1);
        }
     }

     return null;
}
```

And it does seem to work.

When I parse the certificate and call the method, I get the following output:

```
Extern.Example.Example@volkswagen.de
```

However, I don't know how to get `UPN` from the certificate, so I just decided to invoke the method with the if condition removed and iterate through all possible alternative names like so:

```
public static String getSANOtherNameUPN(X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateParsingException
 {
     Collection<List<?>> subjectAlternativeNames = cert.getSubjectAlternativeNames();

     for (List<?> subjectAlternativeName : subjectAlternativeNames)
     {
         System.out.println(subjectAlternativeName);
     }

     return null;
 }
```

The output as follows:

```
[0, [B@3cd1a2f1]
[1, Extern.Example.Example@volkswagen.de]
```

I guess that the 0th element is what I need, although it doesn't look like `EXAMPLE@vw.vwg` at all.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is the method for extracting rfc822 name correct?
2. What do I get as the 0th element? Is it UPN? If so, how to make it look like a readable string? (preferably without using 3rd party's libs)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `0` indicates that is is `otherName` as explained in the [`docs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSubjectAlternativeNames()). The format of those bytes is ASN.1 DER encoded form of the name as also explained in the docs. I would guess that `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);` might give you what you want but first you have to extract those bytes from ASN1 DER encoded form.

Comment: Basically, I've found something like that https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=hsj-xiaokang/springboot-shiro-cas-mybatis/springboot-shiro-cas-mybatis-master/cas-4.2.5/cas-server-support-x509/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/adaptors/x509/authentication/principal/X509SubjectAlternativeNameUPNPrincipalResolver.java

Method name resolvePrincipalInternal

But it looks so deprecated and old...

Is there a better way?